# ¿Cómo puedo comprobar si un texto está en otra columna de un CSV usando pandas?

Tags: python, string, pandas, csv

En la organización para la que trabajo hay un bonito caos en los datos, así que muchas veces tengo que buscarme la vida con pequeños programas de python.

En este me he atascado. Tengo dos listados de clientes (histórico y activos) y quiero ver cuáles han dejado de serlo. Para más lío, en la tabla de históricos tengo sus nombre en formato Nombre Apellidos y en el de activos, Apellidos, Nombre. Los he puesto en un mismo CSV, quitando el nombre a los clientes activos con la idea de buscar una cadena en la otra.

Algo como esto

Historicos;Activos

José Antonio Zaldúa;Zaldúa

Joaquim Rifé;Rifé

Juan Carlos Pérez;Pérez

Johan Cruyff;Cruyff

Juan Manuel Asensi;Asensi

Antonio Olmo;Olmo

Tente Sánchez;Sánchez

Bernd Schuster;Schuster

José Ramón Alexanko;Popescu

José Mari Bakero;Guardiola

Lo que quiero es que imprima solo los dos últimos nombres de la lista (que no están en la lista de actuales.
He intentado esta aproximación

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('clientes.csv',  sep=';')
for historicos in df["Historicos"]:
for actuales in df["Actuales"]:
    if historicos in actuales:
   # seguiría el código
```

pero obtengo el error
'in ' requires string as left operand, not float.

¿dónde me he perdido? Gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi propuesta no requiere pandas ni csv. Simplemente necesita dos archivos con los nombres en cualquier orden y formato. Esta solución te dice que nombres del segundo archivo están en el primer archivo.

Usare estos archivos como ejemplo:

Historico:

```
Juan andres perez
rodrigo soto
juan Bernales
maria del carmen saldias
rosaura lopez chandia
```

Activos:

```
del carmen saldias maria
rosaura lopez Chandia
jaime garcia
olave teodoro
andres perez, juan
soto, rodrigo
bernales, juan
```

Para comparar si dos nombres son iguales (Juan andres perez y andres perez, juan), los separamos en sus partes, convertimos a minúsculas, y ordenamos alfabeticamente:

```
Juan andres perez -> ['andres', 'juan', 'perez']
andres perez, juan -> ['andres', 'juan', 'perez']
```

para reducir el espacio, juntamos las partes y calculamos el *hash*

```
['andres', 'juan', 'perez'] -> "andres juan perez" -> -4647429608740649888
```

Entonces, si tengo dos nombres que producen el mismo hash, son el mismo nombre, sin importar el orden (Nombre-Apellido, Apellido-Nombre), ni el uso de Mayúsculas/minúsculas, ni la presencia de comas entremedio.

Ahora el problema se reduce a tomar un archivo (historico) y llenar una lista con los hash. Luego recorre el otro archivo (activos), calculando el hash para cada nombre y viendo si existe o no en el historico.

```
def normaliza(persona):
    """
    Calcula el hash de una nombre.

    El nombre viene en cualquier orden
    """
    partes = []
    for parte in persona.split():
        # Eliminar aqui los caracteres que no son parte
        # del nombre (sólo ',' por el momento)
        if parte[-1] == ',':
            parte = parte[:-1]
        # Normalizar nombre a minusculas y agregarlo a la lista
        partes.append(parte.lower())

    # Ordenar alfabeticamente el nombre y convertirlo a string.
    partes.sort()
    nombre = " ".join(partes)
    # Retornar el hash del nombre
    return nombre.__hash__()

def busca_persona(persona, lista):
    hash = normaliza(persona)
    return hash in lista

historico = []
with open('historico.txt') as historicos:
    for persona in historicos:
        persona = persona.strip()
        historico.append(normaliza(persona))

with open('activos.txt') as activos:
    for persona in activos:
        persona = persona.strip()
        print(persona, end="")

        if busca_persona(persona, historico):
            print(" existe")
        else:
            print("")
```

produce:

```
del carmen saldias maria existe
rosaura lopez Chandia existe
jaime garcia
olave teodoro
andres perez, juan existe
soto, rodrigo existe
bernales, juan existe
```

**Uso**

Este código sirve de base para producir un archivo de salida con nombres seleccionados. Se puede modificar para producir los nombres repetidos, o los nombres únicos, o poblar directamente los pandas.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que lo que buscas es lo siguiente ( usaré otro DataFrame como ejemplo... ):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'historicos':['A','B','C','D'], 'actuales':['A','B','C','G']})
```

Clientes que se mantienen:

```
len(df[df['actuales'].isin(df['historicos']) == True])
```

Cliente que han abandonado o han dejado de ser:

```
len(df[~df['actuales'].isin(df['historicos']) == True])
```

Salu2 !